# Apache2 download of my cgi sources

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I have an `Ubuntu`-computer with `Apache` 2.4.6 where i configured my

> /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/serve-cgi-bin.conf

like this:

```
<Directory "/home/plfsign/cgi-bin">
       AllowOverride None
       Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
       Require all granted
       AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
</Directory>
```

All other options are default, also the file `plfsign.cgi` has executable (+x) permission:

```
 LANG=c sudo ls -l /home/plfsign/cgi-bin/plfsign.cgi
 -rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 1001 Feb  4 16:19 /home/plfsign/cgi-bin/plfsign.cgi
```

Also I do

```
a2enmod cgi
```

But when I do

```
 curl http://my_local_host_ip/cgi-bin2/plfsign.cgi
```

download of sources of plfsign.cgi is done but not execution result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a ScriptAlias directive before your Directory directory:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin2/ /home/plfsign/cgi-bin/
```